# Why isn't .toLocaleTimeString converting timezones

Tags: javascript, node.js

My goal for this is to convert timezone's given the current time. I've tried switching from date.toLocaleTimeString to date.toLocaleString, with no results. I've tried changing the timezone I wanted it to display, from America/Denver to America/Phoenix. Again with no result. Although it does change the time to Central time, just not Mountain or Pacific. All it gives is the same time as Eastern. Here is my code:

```
    const date = new Date();
    var ESTtime = date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {timezone: "America/New_York"});
    var CSTtime = date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {timeZone: "America/Chicago"});
    var MSTtime = date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {timezone: "America/Denver"});
    var PSTtime = date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {timezone: "America/Los_Angeles"});
    console.log("EST: " + ESTtime);
    console.log("CST: " + CSTtime);
    console.log("MST: " + MSTtime);
    console.log("PST: " + PSTtime);
```

The result gives:

```
EST: 6:10:58 PM
CST: 5:10:58 PM
MST: 6:10:58 PM
PST: 6:10:58 PM
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct option name is `timeZone`, not <s>`timezone`</s>. The only case where you got it correctly is Chicago. Others ignore this option completely (defaulting to your local time), since <s>`timezone`</s> is not a recognized option name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) and [moment-timezone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-timezone) packages to change your date's timezone:

```
const moment = require('moment')
const timezone = require('moment-timezone')

var ESTtime = moment(date).timezone("America/New_York").toLocaleString()
```